# Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoBarCodeScanner' in React native (v 0.64.3)

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, node-modules, package.json

I've been working on a legacy react native project (react native version 0.64.3) and I'm trying to install the library expo-barcode-scanner, but after installation if I import the package, it is throwing an error saying "Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoBarCodeScanner' "

Expo version is 6.7.3.
The version of unimodules that I've installed is 0.11.0.
Please advise.

So far I have tried downgrading the expo-barcode-scanner library version from 12.x to 9.x but it is not working properly and it is throwing an error with the sub module "@unimodules/react-native-adaptor".
I've also tried deleting the node modules folder and reinstalling all the node packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use expo libs in a react native app you might need to add the [expo](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) package to your project (formerly known as [unimodules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unimodules))

Comment: Hi, as mentioned above, I've already added expo package to my RN package but it didn't work, it's still throwing an error when I tried to access the screen with the barcode scanner component in it.